# How to make Fultter (Material Button) overlay appear on top using Window manager params from java.class?

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-layout, overlay

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4TFm.jpg**)

### I have tried to make an overlay button from java using the x and y params and it work fine .

but i want to make the

> material button

on the flutter side to be **appear on top other apps** .
i don't wanna use an external package so i want to use the **window manager** from **java** to move the material button in
flutter ?

how ?

i wanna use it in Android device .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package [flutter_overlay_window](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window) it works on android using the WindowManager.LayoutParams so it helps to display any flutter widget on top of other apps on the screen. so if you don't wanna use external package you can check the source code it's in java